# Getting content cannot be displayed error when adding a checkbox on a pageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce-component, pageblocktable

I have a component which contains a pageBlockTable. I am trying to add checkboxes to the pageBlockTable.

The component is as follows: MyComponent

```
<apex:component controller="ComponentController">
   <apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperClassList}" var="wrapperObject">
         <apex:column headerValue="Select">
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrapperObject.selected}"/>
         </apex:column>
         .
         .
         other columns
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:component>
```

I have created a wrapper class to handle the usage of checkbox in the corresponding controller

```
public with sharing class ComponentController { 
   public List<SObjectWrapperClass> wrapperClassList {get; set;}

   public ComponentController() {
      wrapperClassList = new List<SObjectWrapperClass>();
   }
   .
   // other code 
   .
   //happens couple of times in the code
   wrapperClassList.add(new SObjectWrapperClass(sobj, false); 
   .
   //wrapper class
   public class SObjectWrapperClass {
      public Sobject sobj {get; set;}
      public Boolean selected {get; set;}

      public sObjectWrapperClass(Sobject sobj, Boolean isSelected) {
        this.sobj = sobj;
        this.selected = isSelected;
      }
   }

}
```

The problem is when i refresh the page where this component is being used, it gives me the following error:

*Content cannot be displayed: c:MyComponent must occur between tags*

Now when I comment out the column holding the checkbox, everything works fine and the table is displayed. I dont know what "tags" I am missing. I am pretty sure this issue is due to the checkbox since if I just comment the checkbox line like,

```
<apex:column headerValue="Select">
   <!--<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrapperObject.selected}"/>-->
</apex:column>
```

it just shows a empty Select column.

Am I doing it wrong or is there some other issue. 
Help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<apex:inputCheckbox>` should be wrapped by `<apex:form>`

```
     <apex:form>
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperClassList}" var="wrapperObject">
             <apex:column headerValue="Select">
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrapperObject.selected}"/>
             </apex:column>
             .
             .
             other columns

     </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:form>
```

Comment: Its not working, gives me this error: Error: <apex:column> must be the direct child of either <apex:dataTable> or <apex:pageBlockTable>

Comment: could you try moving the `form` tag before `pageBlockTable` ?

Comment: Ooops, my bad, I was putting the form inside the table. It worked now. Thanks for the help.